# Why is the if-statement not working in my java code?

Tags: java, if-statement

I just started a java class at uni, and am trying to solve a practise exercise where the code reads two angles of a triangle and outputs the third angle.

I wrote an if-statement to make sure the sum of the three angles would never be larger than 180, but the terminal seems to ignore the "else" part of the if-statement completely.

What am I missing?

Originally, I had written "if (triangle == 180) ...", then "if (triangle != 180) .." etc, switching things around. But the "else" is still ignored. In the below code snippet I added a separate int for the triangle, and another one for the sum of all angles.

This is the code I'm working with now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner wheatley = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Write two angles of a triangle.");

    int firstAngle = wheatley.nextInt();
    wheatley.nextLine();
    int secondAngle = wheatley.nextInt();
    wheatley.nextLine();

    int thirdAngle = 180 - firstAngle - secondAngle;

    int angleSum = firstAngle + secondAngle + thirdAngle;

    int triangle = 180;

    if (angleSum == triangle) {
      System.out.println("The third angle is " + thirdAngle + " degrees.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("This is not a triangle.");
    }
  }
}
```

After compiling the code and inputting the two angles I get the following result:

"Write two angles of a triangle.
200
200
The third angle is -220 degrees."

I was expecting:

"Write two angles of a triangle.
200
200
This is not a triangle."

Comment: What if you enter -1000 and -2000 for the angles? PLEASE debug your code and think about what you have written, how it will behave and why it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

The program runs fine, your logic is flawed here

```
int thirdAngle = 180 - firstAngle - secondAngle;
int angleSum = firstAngle + secondAngle + thirdAngle;
```

which is basically

firstAngle + secondAngle + 180 - firstAngle - secondAngle = 180

You are calculating third angle assuming that your figure is a triangle which is why you will always get triangle as a result

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, `angleSum` will always be 180 by virtue of how it's defined.

`c = 180 - a - b`, so following basic algebra `a + b + c = 180`

You need to put a restriction on the sum of your two input angles being smaller than 180, or the third angle being positive (which boils down to the same thing). Additionally, the two input angles should also be greater than zero.

```
if (firstAngle > 0 && secondAngle > 0 && thirdAngle > 0) {
  System.out.println("The third angle is " + thirdAngle + " degrees.");
} else {
  System.out.println("This is not a triangle.");
}
```